# Why is struct.unpack() throwing an exception when my strings are the correct length?

Tags: python, struct

I have a file where some lines are metadata I can ignore and some lines are the printed results of struct.pack calls.  Say that f.txt is:

```
key: 3175
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
key: 3266
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

In this case, the lines starting with "key" are the metadata and the byte strings are the values I want to extract.  Also in this case, the two byte string lines were produced with struct.pack('d', 0).  The following code is what I would like to do:

```
import struct
for line in open('f.txt', 'r'):      
  # if not metadata, remove newline character and unpack
  if line[0:3] != 'key':
    val = struct.unpack('d', line[0:-1])
    appendToList(val) # do something else with val
```

With this, I get: "struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8".

If we modify the code slightly:

```
import struct
for line in open('f.txt', 'r'):      
  # if not metadata, remove newline character and unpack
  if line[0:3] != 'key': print line[:-1]
```

then the output is as expected:

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

If I put the byte string directly into the unpack call then, I have success:

```
import struct
# successful unpacking
struct.unpack('d', '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

I have tried passing the following variations of line to unpack, all of which give the same result:

```
str(line)
repr(line)
b"%s" % line
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is not happening in the very last line of the file, which might be missing a newline?

Comment: The first call to unpack is unsuccessful, so this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your string in txt file:

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

which in python it acturally is:

```
\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00
```

so you should parse this string and convert it. for your sample, use following code can get what you want:

```
s = line.strip().split('\\x')
r = ''
for v in s:
    if len(v) > 0:
        print v
        r += struct.pack('b', int(v, 16))
val = struct.unpack('d', r)[0]
print val
```

Comment: Don't add strings, `''.join` them. Strings are immutable so repeatedly adding them is very slow.

Comment: @arbenson, Since you obviously don't care about performance, why not write the `repr()` of the floats to the file and read them back in with `float()`

Answer (score 3):

The actual bytes in your text file are the string-escaped bytes you see at a python console, not the binary bytes they represent.

For example, your text file contains `\x00` (four bytes long), not the null byte (one byte long).

You need to unescape this text (convert it to binary form) before struct can work on it.

**(NOTE that your file format is not very good because you could conceivably have a line that is a number but starts with 'key:'!  E.g. `'key: \x00\x00\x00'` is a valid number `6.8388560679e-313`! If you alternate between metadata and value every other line, you should just keep track of what line number you are on and parse accordingly.)**

There is a much simpler solution than the others here.

Python has a built-in codec called [`string_escape`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) that will convert python-escape codes into the binary bytes they represent:

```
for line in thefile:
    if line[0:3] != 'key':
        binaryline = line[:-1].decode('string_escape')
        val = struct.unpack('d', binaryline)
```

If you have a big list of these double values and want to store them efficiently in an array structure, consider using the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module instead of `struct`:

```
vals = array.array('d')

for line in thefile:
    if line[0:3] != 'key':
        binaryline = line[:-1].decode('string_escape')
        # appends binaryline to vals array, interpreting as a double
        vals.fromstring(binaryline)
```